# Which is THE most significant change to make Windows restart faster?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, bloatware

In April 2022 I updated Windows 10 on my laptop from
version 1803 (build 17134.1246) to version 21H2 (build 19044.1682).
I was shocked to realize that a normal restart would now take 45
minutes!
Back in 1803 I cannot recall that it ever took more than 10 minutes.

Microsoft may have done a lot of changes over the last four years to
crapify their operating system, but *which* of these changes has had
such a devastating impact that it effectively bricks my laptop?

#### My question

*Which is ***the*** most significant change I can make to Windows 10
(Windows 11) to  speed up the restart?*

My hard drive is an HDD (*hard disk drive*), but I am curious to learn
how I can speed up the restart on an SSD (*solid-state drive*)
as well.
<sup>1</sup>

On an SSD the bad implications from bloatware might have more to do
with using up *space* on the hard drive than making the computer
sluggish.
For such an example, see this
[answer to a question on how to disable the DiagTrack service and
stop Windows it from piling up useless data on the hard drive](https://superuser.com/a/1719694).

But also for an SSD I would like to know what can be done to use less
CPU and memory on pointless activities.
– Even on an SSD computer I have often met the agonizing
**(Not Responding)** message in the title bar of my applications.

#### Reference

- [Answer to a question on how to disable the crapware DiagTrack
  service](https://superuser.com/a/1719694)

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't tell me to replace my 2 terabytes HDD with an SSD!
That's not what I am asking about here.

Comment: You could replace the 2 TB HDD with a 4 TB HDD and short-stroke it ;)

Comment: Just installing an SSD should significantly speed up your restart time, but you can also check to make sure you have "Fast Start-up" enabled. Keep in mind sometimes having this feature turned on can affect certain devices from starting up properly. Usually high end video break out boxes and such.

Comment: This whole question is built around the faulty premise that 45 minutes (and eventually 6 minutes) to reboot a system is simply a symptom of newer versions of Windows getting slower. Even with an HDD it should be more like 45 *seconds*, and with a decent SSD something under 15 seconds should normally be attainable. Chances are you either have faulty hardware or in your quest to ‘de-crapify’ the OS you have broken it

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my post. I will keep it in mind the next time I buy a new laptop.

Comment: I'm fascinated with people who _don't have access to my laptop_
conclude that "the disk is probably rife with bad sectors or has some
bare-metal hardware problem", or that I 
"have broken the OS [i.e. Windows]".
The fact is that blocking the DiagTrack service _alone_ has made
**_my_** laptop restart in less than 8 minutes instead of about
45 minutes.
Rather than have you _guessing_ what is wrong with my laptop, I would
be much more interested in reading for example what effect blocking
the DiagTrack service has had on _your_ laptop.

Comment: @Henke: Well I must confess that my (rather old) personal laptop has had an issue for quite a while where it takes about 2 minutes to boot, when previously it would take about 10-20 seconds to get to the login screen. I vaguely recall the problem either started when I upgraded the nVidia drivers or when I disabled one of those pesky Intel utilities. Your post encouraged me to try to get it working properly again. Among other things I tried disabling the DiagTrack service and I can assure you it made absolutely zero difference.

Comment: Now, that's a feedback I honestly appreciate. – Maybe disheartening in one way, but most of all valuable information for anyone reading these comments. 
(I'm still guessing my case may have to do with my laptop having an HDD.)

Comment: I have come to realize that this question is wrongly asked.
The problem I had was very similar to what is asked in
[this question](https://superuser.com/q/681003),
except that in my case it's the _disk_ usage (not the CPU) that is constantly at 100%.
This problem happens every time I allow Windows Update to install a KB update.
Typically, the day after the KB update was installed,
TiWorker.exe hijacks my computer for some 2-3 hours.
During this time, it's practically impossible to use it.
For example, a simple restart may take 45 minutes.
This never happened in build version 1803.

Answer (score 6):

A boot time of 10 minutes already seems pretty horrifying to me,
although you apparently have grown used to it.
The fact that after a large update of your disk this has increased
to 45 minutes seems very alarming to me.

I suggest to:

- First step is to check your disk status by its SMART data.
  If you don't have an application for that, you could use
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy),
  which will analyze your SMART attributes and mark them as good or bad.
  You may also add a screenshot of it to your post.
  If the disk comes out as bad, it should be replaced.
- Second, and only if the SMART data is perfectly good, you should
  run `chkdsk` to check the file system for errors.
- If everything is good, you should analyze your boot times to find out
  what is taking so much time. See the article
  [4 BootVis Alternatives to Analyze Windows Boot Performance](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/analyze-windows-7-performance-with-microsoft-windows-performance-toolkit/)
  for tools such as WinBootInfo and Soluto
  (although most are old and unsupported, they may still work).
  You could this way find and fix the application that is slowing the boot.

Comment: Thanks for my answering my question.
I took a quick look at
[Alternatives to Analyze Windows Boot Performance](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/analyze-windows-7-performance-with-microsoft-windows-performance-toolkit/).
If I have the time, I may want to look into
[WinBootInfo 1.02](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=3214)
and/or
[Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit for Windows 10, 2004](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install#other-adk-downloads).
Thanks.

Comment: I should have perhaps answered that the best improvement you can do is replace your disk by an SSD.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong...  10 minutes is way to long, and 45?   Thats insane.

Comment: I tend to agree: the disk is probably rife with bad sectors or has some bare-metal hardware problem. Even the "six minutes" the OP quoted as the improvement after (specious) changes is suspect. Both my work and home computers (with radically different specs) boot to desktop in under 30 seconds. Of course, *some* time is probably spent in timeout-based retry loops running his spoofed executables

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the helpful tool
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)!
Today I finally decided to install it and see what it had to say
about my hard drive.
As I haven't previously used Speccy, I wasn't sure what to expect.
At least
[it looks like there is nothing wrong with my hard drive](https://i.imgur.com/UsKjGNt.png),
which is good to know (and a relief of course).
Thanks again for my answering my question.
~ * ~
I need to rewrite my self-answer
(or write a completely new one), as I've realized it doesn't
explain the problems I describe in the question.

Answer (score 4):

> *Which is **the** most significant change I can make to Windows 10
> (Windows 11) to speed up the restart?*

– My own answer (for now) is that blocking/disabling the DiagTrack
service is *the* most significant change I can make to to speed up
the restart (on an HDD).
Sections 1-3 below show three different ways to do this.
Section 4 is strictly speaking not an answer to the question, but
rather some extras that I think my future self will be interested in.

The DiagTrack service (in version 21H2 known as *Connected User
Experiences and Telemetry*) is [a Windows service that transmits
diagnostic and usage information](https://www.technewstoday.com/connected-user-experiences-and-telemetry/#what-is-connected-user-experiences-and-telemetry) to Microsoft.
In other words, for me as a user, this service is useless.
As it turns out, it makes my computer so sluggish that I can hardly
use it.
So it's actually *much worse* than useless.

#### 1. Disable the DiagTrack service in Windows Services

Hit <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type (or paste) `services.msc`
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Sort by name and look for *Connected User Experiences and Telemetry*.
Double-click that service.

At *Service status: Running*, click **Stop**.
At *Startup type: Automatic*, change to **Disabled**.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image: Stop and disable the DiagTrack service.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

Make a software restart of the computer – press
<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed
by <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>.
– With this *single* change it now takes less than 8 minutes for
Windows to start up – including the time it takes to log in.

You may have to do this every time
[Windows Update installs a new build version](https://www.windowscentral.com/using-windows-update-install-new-builds-windows-10-technical-preview).

#### 2. Disable the DiagTrack service from the command line

Alternatively, the DiagTrack service can be disabled from the command
line as follows.

Open the command line as administrator –
hit <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then run :
<sup>1</sup>
`net stop DiagTrack & sc config DiagTrack start= disabled`

Expect a response like :
`The Connected User Experiences and Telemetry service was stopped successfully.`
or :
`The Connected User Experiences and Telemetry service is not started.`
and :
`[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS`

#### 3. Block the DiagTrack service *permanently* in the registry

A third alternative to prevent the DiagTrack service from running
again is to *block* it by renaming its corresponding registry key.

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `regedit` and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
In the navigation bar, paste
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DiagTrack`,
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Right-click `DiagTrack` and choose **Rename**.
Paste/type for example `DiagTrack-BLOCKED!!` and press
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Restart for it to take effect.

As long as you don't restore the original name, the DiagTrack service
is now *permanently* blocked and will never run again (well, not
until Windows Update installs a new build version).

---

##### How to restore the DiagTrack service

If you later want to run the DiagTrack service again, just remove the
suffix `-BLOCKED!!` so that the original name `DiagTrack` is restored.

Then *enable* and *restart* the service :
`sc config DiagTrack start= auto & net start DiagTrack`
Restart the computer.

#### 4. More suggestions to make Windows more responsive (optional)

What I describe in this section is highly dependent on my personal
preferences – so just disregard whatever you disagree with.

*Disclaimer*
If you try out any of the suggestions below, I rather strongly
recommend doing *one and only one* change at a time, and making a
*software restart* after each change.
Otherwise you might not know what to revert if a change turns out to
have undesirable results.

##### 4a. Disable Windows Update

To disable Windows Update, in the registry add the suffix `-BLOCKED!!`
to the following two keys :
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc`
If you want more details, see this
[answer on how to permanently disable Windows Update](https://superuser.com/a/1720522).

##### 4b. Disable Microsoft Edge

There are quite a few suggestions on
[how to disable Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1734596).

##### 4c. More services that I block

My perception of Windows Defender is that it acts more like a virus
*malware* than an *anti*-virus *goodware*.
In short, I don't want it in my computer.
To get rid of it, I use the same technique again – I rename the key
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinDefend`
to `WinDefend-BLOCKED!!`.
This case is bit more tricky though, as I need to restart in
*Safe mode* to rename the key.
For more details, see this [answer on how to disable Windows Defender](https://superuser.com/a/1721132).

There are two more registry keys to which I add the suffix
`-BLOCKED!!` :
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService`
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysMain`

The `TermService` key corresponds to the **Remote Desktop Services**.
By disabling it, I get [one less security vulnerability](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-better-secure-your-microsoft-remote-desktop-protocol-connections/)
to worry about.

The `SysMain` key corresponds to the **SysMain** service which [was
named PreFetch or SuperFetch in earlier versions of Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-superfetch-prefetch-ssd).
*A malfunction can make the SysMain service cause high CPU usage.*

##### 4d. Services that I disable

As I normally don't use the Internet Information Services (IIS)
Server,
I might as well disable its service
*Application Host - tasks for IIS* :
`net stop AppHostSvc & sc config AppHostSvc start= disabled`

The [*Connected Devices Platform Service*](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-disable-connected-devices-platform-service-cdpsvc-to-fix-high-disk-usage/) makes no sense to me :
`net stop CDPSvc & sc config CDPSvc start= disabled`

I don't use the [*Downloaded Maps Manager*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/24df7f21-a883-404e-95b1-3ddc08833735/services-stopped-in-server-2016-preview#f2f34392-58c2-4f85-8e50-b08bca513988) :
`net stop MapsBroker & sc config MapsBroker start= disabled`

[*The Diagnostic Policy Service is [...] notorious for hogging up the
system resources*](https://techcult.com/fix-service-host-diagnostic-policy-service-high-cpu) :
`net stop DPS & sc config DPS start= disabled`

---

###### How to restore any of the disabled services

`sc config <service-name> start= demand`

*For example* :
`sc config AppHostSvc start= demand`

##### 4e. Executables that I prevent from running

Here are some `.exe` files that I don't want to run on my computer.
To stop them, I simply replace them with *empty files*
which have the exact same names.
But before I do that, I first save the original file in a zip file and
leave it in the same directory as the original file.
I might need to [take full control of the file](https://superuser.com/a/1734455) before I can replace it.
<sup>2</sup>

`C:\Windows\System32\CompatTelRunner.exe`
`C:\Windows\System32\WerFault.exe`
`C:\Windows\System32\WerFaultSecure.exe`
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe`

---

In a command line opened as administrator, I run :

```
cd C:\Windows\System32 && takeown /f CompatTelRunner.exe /a
 && icacls CompatTelRunner.exe /grant Administrators:f
```

and

```
cd C:\Windows\System32 && takeown /f WerFault.exe /a
 && icacls WerFault.exe /grant Administrators:f
```

and

```
cd C:\Windows\System32 && takeown /f WerFaultSecure.exe /a
 && icacls WerFaultSecure.exe /grant Administrators:f
```

and

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64 && takeown /f OneDriveSetup.exe /a
 && icacls OneDriveSetup.exe /grant Administrators:f
```

##### 4f. Adjusting for performance

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `sysdm.cpl` (and hit
<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Click the *Advanced* tab, and then *Performance* > **Settings...**.
In the **Visual Effects** tab, I choose **Custom** and check the
following three settings :

- *Animate controls and elements inside windows*
- *Show window contents while dragging*
- *Smooth edges of screen fonts*

[image: 'System Properties' > 'Performance Options' > 'Visual Effects']

##### 4g. Maybe turn off background apps?

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and click **Privacy**.
In the left pane scroll down and click **Background apps**.
At the top of the right pane – where it says
*Let apps run in the background* – turn it **Off**.

#### 5. Final remarks

After spending three weeks full time on unbricking my laptop – bricked
by a Windows Update – I finally feel that it starts up within
(almost) reasonable time, *and* that it's now mostly acceptably
responsive.
My laptop now restarts in less than 6 minutes – including the time
it takes to log in *and* start some of my basic files and
applications.
I still wish it would restart faster, but 6 minutes instead of 45
minutes on every restart – that's clearly a considerable improvement.

Actually, I can restart my laptop in less than *3 minutes* if –
instead of making software restart – I shut it down
(<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> and
<kbd>**U**</kbd>) and then restart it by pressing the physical power
button.
(I believe such a restart will not install any updates that may have
been downloaded by Windows Update.)

#### References

- [The DiagTrack service collects and transmits diagnostic and usage
  information](https://www.technewstoday.com/connected-user-experiences-and-telemetry/#what-is-connected-user-experiences-and-telemetry)
- [How to use Windows Update to install new builds of Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/using-windows-update-install-new-builds-windows-10-technical-preview)
- [*Never, ever* run `sc delete`. – It will destroy your registry!](https://superuser.com/q/1585391)
- [Answer on how to completely and permanently disable Windows Update](https://superuser.com/a/1720522)
- [How to disable Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1734596)
- [Answer on how to disable Windows Defender](https://superuser.com/a/1721132)
- [Security vulnerabilities in Remote Desktop Protocol connections](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-better-secure-your-microsoft-remote-desktop-protocol-connections/)
- [The *SysMain* service was named *PreFetch* or *SuperFetch* in
  earlier versions of Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-superfetch-prefetch-ssd)
- [How to disable the Connected Devices Platform Service (`CDPSvc`)](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-disable-connected-devices-platform-service-cdpsvc-to-fix-high-disk-usage/)
- [The Downloaded Maps Manager is
  *just a left over from the base Windows (10)*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/24df7f21-a883-404e-95b1-3ddc08833735/services-stopped-in-server-2016-preview#f2f34392-58c2-4f85-8e50-b08bca513988)
- [How to disable the Diagnostic Policy Service](https://techcult.com/fix-service-host-diagnostic-policy-service-high-cpu/#Method_5_Disable_the_Diagnostic_Policy_Service_and_delete_SRUDBdat_file)
- [How to take full control of a system file](https://superuser.com/a/1734455)
- [How to Take Ownership of Files and Folders in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/301768/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows/)
- [Take ownership of a file or folder from the command-line](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/take-ownership-of-file-or-folder/)
- [Some methods to fix a slow Windows 10 computer](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-fix-slow-computer-problem-in-windows-10-pc)
- [Windows 10 debloater by Sycnex](https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater/blob/master/Windows10DebloaterGUI.ps1)

---

<sup>1</sup>
[*Never, ever* run `sc delete`!](https://superuser.com/q/1585391)

<sup>2</sup>
Since for each file, I save a zip file containing the original
`.exe` file, I can easily restore them if needed.

Comment: I admire the effort you made writing this, this could be a helpful answer. I'm sorry to say that this, as it is now, is, unfortunately, a terrible answer. First of all, it doesn't answer your own question (THE and MOST significant change) but most of all your suggestions to e.g. blocking services without explaining what they are used for, doesn't help anyone. It would be great if you could improve on that, so it will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I believe they helped me improve my answer.

Comment: Much better, thanks +1! I'll try that myself as well...

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: How much were you able to shave off from the 45 minutes reboot time?

Comment: > _How much were you able to shave off from the 45 minutes reboot time?_
**Answer**:
~ 45 - 8 = ~ 37 minutes.
The 45 minutes is not very exact, as it includes starting some of my
personal files and programs.
A _hardware_ restart (winkey+x, u, u, followed by pressing the physical
button once the computer is shut down) is always faster than a
_software_ restart (winkey+x, u, r).
I believe this has to do with Windows Update running _only_ when you
make a software restart.
For me, a hardware restart takes about half the time of a software
restart, in my case ~ 2-4 minutes.

Comment: Wow, that's still very long. None of the computers I've had in the last 10 years took more than 5 minutes to restart and they weren't exactly cutting edge hardware. While I applaud the amount of work you've put into researching this, I feel like you'd get much, much better results by just setting everything up from scratch and I wouldn't be surprised if it would take less of your time. If you wanted to use it as an opportunity to learn something, then sure - been there, done that - but frankly regarding the slow restart issue the results aren't exactly satisfying.

Comment: Nevertheless, 82% faster is impressive. Regarding "software restart" vs "hardware restart": since Windows 8 shutdown actually stops processes and hibernates the system because it's faster. Restart does a proper full shutdown followed by a cold boot.

Comment: This whole answer is wrong.
Today I unblocked DiagTrack and restarted.
It took about 6 minutes, which (unfortunately) is normal for my laptop.
~ * ~
I have strong reason to believe that the slow restart is because of
 [Windows Modules Installer Worker](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-modules-installer-worker-high-cpu-disk-usage), and its exe-file [TiWorker.exe](https://wethegeek.com/how-to-fix-tiworker-exe-high-disk-usage-problems-on-windows-10).
[More on TiWorker.exe](https://digiworthy.com/2020/04/18/tiworker-exe-high-disk-usage-windows-10).